# Why does ScriptManager ignore debug mode when using bundling?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager, bundling-and-minification

On an asp.net webforms site, I am using a ScriptManager with bundling enabled for Webforms and MsAjax as described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx

I have my ScriptManager set up as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

This works as expected when debug is set to false. When I set debug to true, however, I get the same bundle references with minified files. For example, I see something such as the following when debug is false or true:

```
<script src="/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=D6VN0fHlwFSIWjbVzi6mZyE9Ls-4LNrSSYVGRU46XF81" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My expectation is that I should see links to the individual non-minified versions of the webforms script files when debug is set to true. I do see in the article I listed above, however, that the MicrosoftAjax and WebForms ScriptResourceMappings do not reference debug paths. Does anybody have any idea if this is by design? Is this perhaps a limitation due to the changes they had to make to scriptmanager to allow bundling to work with it?